# Creating a timelapse from a directory of jpgs

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this code to create a timelapse from a directory of images. My directory has about 1600 jpgs in it that all start with the date in this format 2020-03-01-time.jpg, 2020-03-02-time-name.jpg, etc. Sorting alphabetically works just fine. It runs, but it seems to only get through a few hundred photos and makes a 3 second long mp4. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm not opposed to moving to python or anything else. Eventually I'll need to pass some parameters in here and I'll attempt to automate it and ftp the output to a webserver.

Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -s hd1080 -vcodec libx264 timelapse.mp4
```

Here is the output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, image2, from '*.jpg':
  Duration: 00:01:06.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'timelapse.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=20 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'timelapse.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 20 fps, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   72 fps= 11 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10663kB time=00:00:03.45 bitrate=25318.0kbits/s speed=0.507x    
video:10661kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.015737%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] frame I:5     Avg QP:23.69  size:223467
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] frame P:33    Avg QP:26.52  size:139314
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] frame B:34    Avg QP:28.49  size:152989
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] consecutive B-frames: 33.3%  8.3%  8.3% 50.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] mb I  I16..4:  2.2% 96.6%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] mb P  I16..4:  2.1% 78.8%  1.5%  P16..4:  9.4%  4.7%  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] mb B  I16..4:  1.1% 20.4%  2.3%  B16..8: 27.6% 13.7%  5.3%  direct:22.7%  skip: 6.9%  L0:33.5% L1:32.2% BI:34.3%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] 8x8 transform intra:93.8% inter:86.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 91.5% 66.0% 17.4% inter: 77.7% 58.7% 2.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 13% 56%  3% 28%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 20% 39%  4%  3%  3%  4%  4%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 28% 12%  5%  7%  7%  6%  7%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 49% 29% 19%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:30.3% UV:24.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] ref P L0: 48.2% 17.7% 17.7% 13.3%  3.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] ref B L0: 83.2% 14.2%  2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] ref B L1: 93.8%  6.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55a43cfb1d00] kb/s:24258.47
```

Comment: Are all of the inputs `.jpg`? Do they all have the same width, height, chroma subsampling (yuvj420p)? Does it work if you use a modern ffmpeg version? [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated to the latest version. I was hoping that would do it. Unfortunately the same issue. I did notice that it always stops in the same place. I ran it with verbose output and saw that it stopped on frame 72. I counted all the files and sure enough file 72 was 0 bytes. I wish there was a way to make it automagically skip a bad file.

Comment: It's worth proving an answer since you found the problem.